# Getting bundle exception while deploying app to Apache Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I'm developing simple application to demonstrate use of Apache Karaf.I have developed one simple maven based dynamic web project in eclipse.Now I want to deploy it in apache karaf.Following is that code-

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;


    public class DemoActivator implements BundleActivator {

        @Override
        public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("STARTING DEMO: hello, world");
        }

        @Override
        public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("STOPPING DEMO");
        }

    }
```

Dependancies in POM.Xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi_R4_core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi_R4_compendium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
 Bundle-SymbolicName: osgi-example
 Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
 Import-Package:com.psl.demo;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT",org.osgi.framework
 Export-Package: com.psl.demo;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
 Bundle-Activator: com.psl.demo.DemoActivator
```

Given path of custom MANIFEST file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now whenever I'm trying to install application in karaf using-

```
install mvn:com.psl/osgi-demo-next/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Im getting error as-

> Error executing command: Error installing bundles: Unable to install
>   bundle mvn:com.psl.demo/osgi-example/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT:
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle:
>   mvn:com.psl.demo/osgi-example/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT

Any solution for this? TIA

Comment: doesn't seem to be in the maven repository. Did you do a mavn clean install?

Comment: @AchimNierbeck -Yes,I did it.

Comment: Can you show us the full pom file?

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because maven coordinates in bundle install command are not correct. Following is syntax for the same:

`karaf@root()> bundle:install mvn:<group-id>/<artifact-id>/<version>`

Please validate the content of `pom.xml` and accordingly put values in above command.

From simplicity perspective, you could check local maven repository to find bundle location and accordingly put values in above `bundle install command`.